# nltk download url authorization issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I tried to update my nltk data with nltk.download() but I got HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required.

When I traced the url in question, I found it in downloader.py

> DEFAULT_URL = 'http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/index.xml'

I then copied that URL and ran it in my browser to find out that it's asking me for a username and password.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NLTK have moved from their googlecode site.

As noted [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527388/python-nltk-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-nltk-downloadbrown-results-in-html-error-40), nltk's new data server is located at http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/. Just update the URL to the new location, and it should hopefully work.

Comment: Thanks @user2979044. I did as you said and it worked.