# 'No Route To Host' error in installing 'NLTK Data'

Tags: python, linux, installation, nltk

I have been trying to install nltk.data for a project. As described in [this documentation](http://www.nltk.org/data.html), I tried to install it using both methods mentioned.

1. Through python:

   import nltk
   nltk.download()

The problem is in the next step, ( please find the screenshot attached).[image: error screenshot]

The error message is:

```
Packages:
Error connecting to server: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

2. Through command line:

`sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data`

This resulted in the same issue too.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998742/nltk-download-url-authorization-issue), my DEFAULT_URL was  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data`. Even after changing it to http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/, I am getting the same problem.

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Can you post the output of `python3 -c 'import nltk; print(nltk.__version__); print(nltk.data.path)'` in your question?

Comment: Please reinstall the latest version of NLTK from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk

Comment: I feel that it might be connected to not having an x-server or similar desktop environment. Cause it doesn't run on my linux server, but it runs fine on my mac, opens up a window (which is impossible on my linus with gui) with menus to install packages.